# SBT project with a Java module in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am learning developing project in IntelliJ.

I started a new SBT project. Now I have two files, one is a Scala script `projectName/src/main/scala/scalaScript.scala` and the other is a Java class `projectName/src/main/java/moduleName/MyClass.java`

The Scala script is used for me to test codes line-by-line in a Scala Console. In oder to test the class I defined in `MyClass.java`, I think I need to compile it first and then `import moduleName.MyClass` in the Scala script. After that, I can use the java class to create objects and do whatever I want.

If I am not using IntelliJ, I just need to go to the java module directory and call `javac -cf myJavaLibrary.jar MyClass.java` to create a jar. Then move `myJavaLibrary.jar` into the same directory as that of my Scala script file.

How do I efficiently do that in IntelliJ? What is the working pipeline?

**Update 1**

I switched to using Scala worksheet. However, after `import moduleName.MyClass`, there is an error saying the module is not found.

```
import bestbuy.Laptop
```

where `bestbuy` is the module name, and `Laptop` is a class. Then the message says:

```
Error:not found: value bestbuy
import bestbuy.Laptop
       ^
Error:(6, 10) not found: value bestbuy
;import bestbuy.Laptop
        ^
Error:(18, 50) not found: value bestbuy
println(MacroPrinter211.printImportInfo({import bestbuy.Laptop;}))
                                                ^
Error:(26, 50) not found: value bestbuy
println(MacroPrinter211.printImportInfo({import bestbuy.Laptop;}))
                                                ^
```

**Update 2**

In the worksheet, you should check the little box in front of "Make project" so that all the source code will be compiled and the byte code will be saved in the target directory where SBT expects. Then I can successfully `import bestbuy.Laptop` in the worksheet.

**However, I am still expecting an answer to my original question.** If I can `import bestbuy.Laptop` in the Scala script file instead of a worksheet. In the worksheet all codes are executed at once, while I would like to execute them one line at a time.

After the project is compiled, I tried executing `import bestbuy.Laptop` in the Scala Console, but got error:

```
scala> import bestbuy.Laptop
<console>:13: error: not found: value bestbuy
       import bestbuy.Laptop
              ^
```

It seems that the console's class path is not properly configured. How can I configure the console's class path?

Answer (score 0):

to use repl-like environment in IntelliJ just create new scala worksheet file and in there you can import your Java class and use it. IDE will compile everything for you.

You can also use terminal, type in `sbt console` and you will have your repl  with your project classes in classpath, so you can import and use them.

Comment: I tried worksheet. It says the module is not found. I guess this is because the java file is not compiled and added to the class path. Am I doing anything wrong? By the way, if I want to stick to my Scala script, do I have to compile my java code manually and add the jar to the library dependency in the project structure dialogue?

Comment: Make sure project is compiled. In worksheet you have little play icon and two checkboxes, one of which is "Make project", check it and click play icon. To test, I created new sbt project, in java created a package and basic class, then I created a worksheet in src directory (dir should not matter) and tried to create new instance of java class. I got same error as you, but after I checked "Make project" it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed works. However, I still want to know a way to run codes line by line in Scala Console.

Comment: sbt is independent from the IDE, you can use terminal inside IDE or any other terminal, just cd to your project folder, run `sbt` and type in `console` now you are in scala repl with your project classes available to import.